# Securing API on sub-domain - users logged in using OAuth providers

Tags: api, asp.net-mvc-4, dotnetopenauth

I have an MVC 4 website (http://myWebsite.com) that uses a few OAuth providers (Google, Facebook, Twitter, MS Live) for users to login - it uses the DotNetOpenAuth library.

I also have an API on the sub-domain (http://api.myWebsite.com).

Upon a user wanting to update a record, I need to check that they have permission (are authorized) to alter the record.

So the question is, how best to authorize the user on an API on the sub-domain?

My thoughts so far entail the following:

I could add the user's authentication token to the API in the HTTP request header, and then I believe I have two options.

i) I create a method on the website that looks after all user permissions and send it the token and ask if the user is authorized.

ii) I add the DotNetOpenAuth dlls to the API solution and then can simply decorate the API methods with the roles that are needed to access them. Would this work?

A third option is to post the updated record back to the website and run authorization their, and then if it passes to send the data on to the API but this seems to smell.

I am sure I am missing something obvious here, hence the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How your users log in is completely orthogonal to how you authorize other clients to call your API sub-domain. Do *not* just accept an authentication token at your API -- authentication, misused as authorization, opens up big security holes.

Authorizing clients to call your API requires an authorization protocol such as OAuth 1 or 2, both of which DotNetOpenAuth supports. Check out the DNOA OAuthAuthorizationServer and OAuthResourceServer sample to get started on adding OAuth 2 support to your API.